# Update Ignore if the updated value will be negative

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Is there a way to check if the result of an update query will be negative, ignore the transaction?

I have the following query:

```
$queryWasUseless = sprintf("UPDATE solution 
                            set SOLUTION_HELPFUL = SOLUTION_HELPFUL - 1
                            WHERE ID_SOLUTION = '%s'", $_POST['id']);
```

Is there a way like if the value to be updated, in this case, the SOLUTION_HELPFUL column will be less than 0, ignore the transaction?

Comment: Your SQL is vulnerable to SQL injection. Be sure to [sanitize your inputs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're always subtracting 1, one way would be to add an `AND SOLUTION_HELPFUL > 0` to your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Didn't think about this. I beg your pardon. Thanks a lot @Jessida

Comment: No problem, sometimes the simple things don't seem simple at first :)